# Python: re.sub single item in list with multiple items

Tags: regex, list, python-2.7

I'm new to Python and trying to use re.sub or other approach to find individual items in a list and replace with multiple items. For example:

```
import re
list = ['abc', 'def']
tolist = []
for item in list:
    a = re.sub(r'^(.)(.)(.)$', '\\1\\2', '\\2\\3', item)
    tolist.append(a)
print tolist  # want: ['ab', 'bc', 'de', 'ef']
```

The '\1\2', '\2\3' part clearly doesn't work, just there to lamely illustrate the idea.

Comment: `list` is a builtin type. Don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: J.F., Lev: Thanks for catching that

Comment: Thanks all for the clarification and ideas. In practice, I'm working with lists of variable length items, i.e. ['abc', 'defg'], and I need to limit the operation to 3-char items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pair characters without regexes:

```
lst = ['abc', 'def']
result = [a+b for chars in lst for a, b in zip(chars, chars[1:])]
print(result)
# -> ['ab', 'bc', 'de', 'ef']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rather generic approach where you have a list of tuples for all the substitutions you want to do with each item:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: subs = [(r'^(.)(.)(.)$', r'\1\2'), (r'^(.)(.)(.)$', r'\2\3')]

In [3]: inlist = ['abc', 'def']

In [4]: [re.sub(*sub, string=s) for s in inlist for sub in subs]
Out[4]: ['ab', 'bc', 'de', 'ef']
```

The second element in each tuple can also be a function, because `re.sub` allows it. I renamed your initial list because `list` is a built-in type name and shouldn't be used for variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> res = []
>>> m = re.compile('(..)')
>>> for items in list:
...   for p in range(0,len(items)):
...     r = m.search(items[p:])
...     if r != None:
...        res.append(r.group())
```

make a regexp that matches two characters and groups them

first for loop, iterate the list

second for loop, character indexes in each list item

search for the character pairs starting at further on offsets

store anything that's found